# Conexión Ajax regresa variable undefined

Tags: javascript

Ayuden Por favor

esto consumiendo un servicio rest con ajax en la cual toda la información llena el combobox , pero me sale undefined y después me sale los registros ;/

```js
$(function () {
   
            $("#cuerpohumano").ready(function () {

   
                $.ajax({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: "http://localhost:2018/servicios/operaciones/CuerpoHumanoCebecera/cuerpoHumano",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                }).done(function (data) {

                    //alert(data);
                    $("#cuerpohumano :nth-child(n+2)").remove();

                    var newoption = "";
                    $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

                            if (item[i] !== "undefined") {
                                console.log(item[i].ID, item[i].DENOMINACION);
                            }
                            
                       
                           
                            newoption = "<option value='" + item[i].ID   + "'>" + item[i].DENOMINACION + "</option>";
                                $("#cuerpohumano").append(newoption);
                            
                        }
                        
                     

                    })
                }).fail(function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    console.log("Error al obtener los datos de Sede Origen, Problema al acceder al URL");

                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: cambia `(item[i] !== "undefined")` por `(typeof(item[i]) !== "undefined")`

Comment: explicame que quieres hacer con estas lineas ` $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {`

Comment: pon un console.log(data) inmediatamente despues de tu evento .done
Para ver que es lo que te está regresando

Comment: puedes agregar el JSON de retorno?

Comment: `undefined` no es un string, si quieres comparar una variable con `undefined` haz esto: `if (miVar !== undefined)` así sin comillas.